# Is it possible to switch between single ended and differential IO 'on the fly' (post configuration) in Xilinx Spartan-6 FPGA

Tags: verilog, xilinx, spartan

I'm writing Verilog code for a Sparatn-6 Xilinx FPGA in which I would like to reconfigure IO during 'runtime' specifically, between single ended and differential IO buffers.

I have read through the list of IO buffer primitives in UG381.pdf but all seem to be fixed single ended or differential (on the pad side)

I have tried instantiating an OBUF and an OBUFDS but have found no way to mux the outputs of the bufs to a single pad, or combine them before or as part of their association with a pad. The wiring of adjacent pads to form differential outputs/inputs seems to be entirely hidden away, as you might expect, but also therefore seems to prevent the use of the OBUF for anything other than the differential function which it doesn't *need* to as such...

What envisage I need is:

```
SELECTABLE_SINGLE_DIFF_OBUFDS #(
   .IOSTANDARD ("LVDS_33")
) my_buf (
   .I       (my_signal),    // logic input (fabric side)
   .IO      (diff_p_out),   // Single ended o/p or Differential +ve (to pin)
   .IOB     (diff_n_out),   // Differential -ve (to pin)
   .MODE    (my_mode == 1)  // mode = 0, single ended output
                            // mode = 1, differential output
);
```

There must be something when you instantiate a OBUF or OBUFDS that configures the underlying SelectIO block's differential capabilities, I guess what I'm looking for is a way to access the underlying block from within Verilog so I can control the configuration of the IO Block from other logic in the FPGA.

Comment: Most single-ended IOs aren't designed to work with differential IOs and vice-versa. Due to that, FPGAs generally only connect single IOs to single bumps. To do what you are asking would likely require some custom analog that would require it's own chip/ASIC. What is the need to switch between the two on the fly?

Comment: @Steveo - thanks for you comments, yes I understand what you're saying - it's seems an unsual thing to need to do. For what it's worth, the reason I'm investigating this is that our client wants one FPGA image that allows boards to be moved between 2 rigs without reflashing. On one rig, Bank 2 goes to a DAC with differential data inputs and on the other rig, Bank 2 goes to 12 RX/TX pairs which are all single ended. The reall issue here is that because it's got an FPGA on it, the expectation is 'it'll just handle everything' right - for now, they get 2 images.

Comment: Understood. One thing that *may* be possible (assuming these boards lose power between switching rigs) is to have a pin that is high for one type of rig and low for another. This pin is used to decide which image to flash. This assumes you can handle multiple images on some flash and/or add some logic to select it at power up. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As long as you only need differential outputs, you can probably get away with just using two single-ended registered outputs and drive the negative output inverted.